# Mybatis Dynamic Prepend

Tags: dynamic, version, mybatis, prepend

I have recently upgraded from mybatis version 2 to 3.3.
    Since mybatis 3.3.0 doesn't support dynamic prepend anymore, we tried to replace as shown below:

```
version 2 query
delete FROM
Employee
where
ID_UNIQUE_KEY = #{uniqueKey}
<dynamic prepend=" and ID_Employee_CODE not in">
<if test="Employees != null">
<isNotEmpty property="Employees">
<iterate open=" (" close=") " conjunction="," property="Employees">
<if test="Employees[].idEmployeeCode != null">
#{Employees[].idEmployeeCode}
</if>
</iterate>
</isNotEmpty>
</if>
</dynamic>
```

replaced it with :

```
delete FROM
Employee
where
ID_UNIQUE_KEY = #{uniqueKey}
<if test="Employees != null and Employees.size() &gt; 0">
and ID_Employees_CODE not in
<foreach close=")" collection="Employees" index="index" item="item" open="(" separator=",">
<if test="item != null and item.idEmployeeCode != null">
#{item.idEmployeeCode}
</if>
</foreach>
</if>
```

The problem with this is if i have a list of not null DTOs(Employees) but the attribute of dto, which is being used in the `query(idEmployeeCode)`, is `null`, then in that case `AND clause(  and ID_Employees_CODE not in)` gets appended to the query with empty (), hence failing it.

We can handle it in java as well..before calling these queries.
Though is there any way to handle it here in queries, considering the amount of queries affected by this is huge.

This was working fine with dynamic prepend.

Any idea on this?

Thanks & Regards,
Nikita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little re-engineering, the `<trim>` tag is a good replacement for `<dynamic>` - and, I think, easier to understand too.

Try this:

```
delete FROM Employee
where
ID_UNIQUE_KEY = #{uniqueKey}
<if test="Employees != null and Employees.size() &gt; 0">
  <trim prefix="and ID_Employees_CODE not in (" suffix=")">
    <foreach collection="Employees" index="index" item="item" separator=",">
      <if test="item != null and item.idEmployeeCode != null">
        #{item.idEmployeeCode}
      </if>
    </foreach>
  </trim>
</if>
```

Comment: What exactly is trim doing here?

Comment: `trim` will not render if nothing inside renders. In this case if all the items are null, you won't get `and ID_EmployeesCode not in ( )`